# Angular2 Property does not exist on type 'any[]' (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, rest, angular

I have a class named **Condition**:

```
export class Condition{
    name: string;
    date: string;
    link: string;
}
```

And a function named **search** that makes http get requests:

```
public search(params: string): Observable<json[]> {
    let queryString = this.serverUrl + params;

     return this.http.get(queryString)
                     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

 }
```

And I get an object to get conditions with specific properties from it. It has absolutely an object array in its **entry** attribute:

```
this.search(`Condition?patient=Patient/107795`).subscribe(data => {
    var conditionArray = data.entry;       // data.entry is absolutely an ARRAY
    for(var condition of conditionArray){
        conditions.push({    //conditions is a Condition[]
            name: condition.resource.code.coding[0].display,
            date: condition.resource.dateRecorded,
            link: "condition/" + condition.resource.id
        });
    }
    } , err => { console.log(err); } );
```

I was started these project **before I wrote these code** with start script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
```

And the project was working as I wanted and no error on the console. However, when I stopped it and started again with the start script, it gives this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'entry' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

Do you know what is wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `search` method should probably return an object, not an array. Declare it as follows:

```
public search(params: string): Observable<any> {
```

Use `any` unless you have a type describing the result, if so, you may use that instead.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change the type of it. It is working now, thanks!